# Calculate various differences in days using DateOffSet using loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas, datetime

given a fame with the next five Saturdays:

```
start_date =
0    04.03.2017
1    11.03.2017
2    18.03.2017
3    25.03.2017
4    01.04.2017
```

and a list which I use for calculating end_dates

```
duration = [4, 8, 15, 22].
```

I would like to create a new frame which based on start_date plus duration, e.g.

```
start_date[0] = duration[0] = 07.03.2017
start_date[1] = duration[0] = 11.03.2017
start_date[2] = duration[0] = 18.03.2017
...
```

I tried solving this using pd.DateOffset:

```
for j in range(len(duration)):
  end_date = []
  for i in start_dates:
      # get offset date, convert it and append it to end_date list
      z = pd.to_datetime(i) + pd.DateOffset(days=duration[(j)])
      end_date.append(z.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
```

However, I get the following output:

```
['07.04.2017', '07.11.2017', '22.03.2017', '29.03.2017', '08.01.2017']
```

Where is the issue? Is it because of the DateOffset function? Unfortunately, I can´t see a pattern regarding the export.

Any hints?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `DateOffset()`.  The problem is you do not specify the date format when you pass your date string to pandas.

So pandas is guessing the date format.  What you should do is passing the `format` parameter when using `to_datetime()`.

```
df
   start_date
0  04.03.2017
1  11.03.2017
2  18.03.2017
3  25.03.2017
4  01.04.2017

df['py_start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

   start_date py_start_date
0  04.03.2017      2017-03-04
1  11.03.2017      2017-03-11
2  18.03.2017      2017-03-18
3  25.03.2017      2017-03-25
4  01.04.2017      2017-04-01

for d in duration:
    df['offset {}'.format(d)] = df['py_start_date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=d)

    start_date py_start_date   offset 4   offset 8  offset 15  offset 22
0  04.03.2017      2017-03-04 2017-03-08 2017-03-12 2017-03-19 2017-03-26
1  11.03.2017      2017-03-11 2017-03-15 2017-03-19 2017-03-26 2017-04-02
2  18.03.2017      2017-03-18 2017-03-22 2017-03-26 2017-04-02 2017-04-09
3  25.03.2017      2017-03-25 2017-03-29 2017-04-02 2017-04-09 2017-04-16
4  01.04.2017      2017-04-01 2017-04-05 2017-04-09 2017-04-16 2017-04-23
```

Comment: I haven´t considered specifying the date format. It does make sense. Your code works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using try & error I found another solution (tested)

```
for j in range(len(duration)):
  date_offset = []
  for i in start_dates:
     k = duration[j]
     d = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%d.%m.%Y")
     d = d + datetime.timedelta(days=k)
     date_offset.append(d.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

  # Transfer date_offset list into four seperate offset series depending on k
  if k == 4:
     offset_4 = pd.Series(date_offset)
  elif k == 8:
     offset_8 = pd.Series(date_offset)
  elif k == 15:
     offset_15 = pd.Series(date_offset) 
  else:
     offset_22 = pd.Series(date_offset)
```

I know it´s not that elegant compared to the posted solution before but it also works. ;)